# Toggle hidden columns data in a row

Tags: javascript, html, rows, hidden

I have two hidden columns in my html table (I've tried to use hidden rows and the toggling worked great, but it messed up my rows count)
I want to toggle the hidden columns data in a row below the row that is shown.
My current state is that it's indeed toggling, but it covers the next row in the table.

Is there a way to create a temporary new row that will be placed below the clicked row that will toggle the hidden column data without hiding the next row?

Any help will be appreciated :)

This is my table which is being populated by PHP script:

```
if($SELECT != false)
{
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($SELECT))
{
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td><label><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"lead\" value=\"".$rows["email"]."\" /></label></td>
        <td>".$rows["createdTime"]."</td>
        <td>".$rows["firstName"]."</td>
        <td>".$rows["lastName"]."</td>
        <td>".$rows["email"]."</td>
        <td>".$rows["phoneNumber"]."</td>
        <td>".$rows["country"]."</td>
        <td>".$rows["ip"]."</td>
        <td>".$rows["affiliate"]."</td>
        <td>".$rows["description"]."</td>
        <td>".$rows["broker"]."</td>
        <td>".$rows["status"]."<br> <br>
        Comment:<b> ".$rows["comment"]."</b></td>
        <td>".$rows["ftd"]."</td>

        <td colspan=\"13\">
        Transaction Id: ".$rows["transaction_id"]."
        <br>
        <br>
        Balance: ".$rows["balance"]."
</td>
    ";
}
}
```

This is my toggle function:

```
$(function() {
$("tr").find("td[colspan=13]").hide();
$("table").click(function(event) {
     if($(event.target).is('input')){
        return;
    }
    else{
    var $target = $(event.target);
    $target.closest("tr").next().find("td").slideToggle(-2000);
 }
});
});
```

Comment: Can you show us what you already have tried?

Comment: Of course! Added :)

Comment: If you trying to hide column then you should get some index of column and set display:none of the individual cell.

Answer (score 0):

First solution :

Why dont you just make a hidden row (after each visible row) with the columns that you want to display.And make it visible after you hover the first row?

Second solution :

Place the hidden data in a div and the displayed data in a div. Let both be childs of the td element. The tr height will scale if the hidden div gets displayed.

Comment: I'm also using TableFilter and it's messing the row counts with the paging function

Comment: Then try this    <tr><td><div class="visible"></div><div class="hidden"></div></td></tr> and make both divs 100% width so they will be displayed vertically